# Parallelization of packet processing

Tags: c++, openmp, packets

As packet processing (statistic calculation, like IP distribution, TTL distribution, etc.) of large PCAP files is comparatively slow, I want to parallelize it.

I am using the C++ library `libtins` for packet reading and processing:

Packet reading

```
FileSniffer sniffer(pcap_path);
for (const auto &pkt : sniffer) {
    this->process_packets(pkt);
}
```

Packet processing (extract)

```
void PcapProcessor::process_packets(const Packet &pkt) {
  // packet count
  packetCount++;
  const PDU *pdu = pkt.pdu();

  if (pdu->find_pdu<IP>()) {
      const IP &ipLayer = pdu->rfind_pdu<IP>();
      // IP distribution
      ip_distribution[ipLayer.src_addr()]++;
      ip_distribution[ipLayer.dst_addr()]++;

      // TTL distribution
      ttl_distribution[ipLayer.ttl()]++;

      // Protocol distribution - layer 3
      protocol_distribution["IP"]++;
  }

 // Protocol distribution - layer 4
 PDU::PDUType p = pdu->inner_pdu()->pdu_type();
 if (p == PDU::PDUType::TCP) {
    protocol_distribution["TCP"]++;
 }
 if (p == PDU::PDUType::UDP) {
    protocol_distribution["UDP"]++;
 }
}
```

whereas `process_packets` consumes most of the processing time. It would be highly time-saving if it could be called for multiple packets in parallel. Is this generally possible, as the amount of packets in `sniffer` is not yet known? If so, must the `std::unordered_map` and `int` Variables used in `process_packets` changed to be thread-safe?

I tried to use OpenMP, by just adding `#pragma openmp parallel for` before the loop, leading to `error: ‘pkt’ implicitly determined as ‘firstprivate’ has reference type #pragma omp task`. Is this not parallelizable at all?

Comment: I don't understand what part of process_packets could take any time. Could it be that the disk read speed is the limiting factor? That FileSniffer may not support the random access required to use OMP, but you can read a bunch of packets into another container maybe and then parallelize that.

Comment: Note that a packet can only have one PDU type, so you may like to use `if else if` instead of multiple `if`.

Comment: Have you tried `for (const auto pkt : sniffer)`?

Comment: You might be better off using Threading Building Blocks  https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/ rather than OpenMP. (But you're going to need to worry about race conditions either way if that code snippet is representative, since it seems very likely that you have races in all of those increments as soon as you're processing more than one packet at the same time).